# xcodebuild can't find cocoapods libraries

Tags: xcode, firebase, unity-game-engine, cocoapods, xcode9.4

I have an xcode project (build from Unity) that uses cocoapods to install Firebase dependencies. It builds fine through the xcode GUI but not using the `xcodebuild` invocation that I use for automated builds:

```
xcodebuild -archivePath "$ARCHIVE_PATH" -project "$(pwd)/repo/quantum_unity/Build/$PLATFORM/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj" -sdk iphoneos -allowProvisioningUpdates -scheme 'Unity-iPhone' -configuration 'Release Development' archive DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=$TEAMID
```

The build fails to find the `FirebaseCore` library in linking.

What needs to change in how I invoke `xcodebuild` so it's able to find the pods installed by cocoapods?

I'm using xcode version 9.4.1.

Comment: Likely need to use -workspace and the xcworkspace instead of the project

Comment: Yup that totally fixed it. If you post an answer then I can accept it! Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use -workspace and the xcworkspace instead of the project.

After installing via CocoaPods and depending on them, always use the Xcode workspace instead of the project.